# How to Encrypt RSA Key in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.android

I have a Windows Code from CCAvenue which works fine in Universal Windows Application but how to achieve the same in Xamarin.Forms?

```
public string EncryptRSA(string plainText, string publicKeyString) 
{
    IBuffer dataBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(plainText, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    var asymmAlg = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
    var publicKey = asymmAlg.ImportPublicKey(CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(publicKeyString), CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo);
    var encryptedData = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(publicKey, dataBuffer, null);
    return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(encryptedData);
}
```

If I copy paste the same code its giving this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: So what happens if you paste that into Xamarin forms?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the question please check

Comment: Added reference windows.foundation.universalapicontract.winmd from nuget?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

Comment: Sorry, I did not find Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts package from Nuget Manager

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use this UWP specific API on other platforms in Xamarin.Forms. I haven't found an alternative library, which would provide this functionality in cross-platform manner, so you will probably have to implement it using platform-specific APIs.

You can use [Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) and create an interface with your `EncryptRSA` method and then implement this interface in the platform heads in your solution. You already have the UWP implementation, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418782/732221) looks like a possible iOS solution and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43532954/732221) is a possible Android implementation.

Comment: I have used possible android implementation but its showing me error "Base.64 does not exists in the current context". Do I have to import Android.Util or what?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to implement the above answer using .SO in Xamarin.Android